# How to get a CGFloat from a NSString?

Tags: objective-c, math

In my current app, I have an equation that typically solves to a pretty long amount of decimal numbers, i.e: 0.12345 or .123 . But the way that I need this to work is to only show say 1 or 2 decimal numbers, so that would essentially produce 0.12 or 0.1 based on the values I mentioned.

In order to do this, I have done the following: Taken my CGFloat to a NSString:

```
CGFloat eX1 = 0.12345
NSLog(@" eX1 = %f", eX1);  //This of course , prints out 0.12345

NSNumberFormatter *XFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
Xformatter.numberStyle=NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
Xformatter.maximumFractionDigits=1;


NSString *eX1F = [formatter stringFromNumber:@(eX1)]; 
NSLog (@"eX1F = %@",eX1F);  //This prints out 0.1
```

But my problem is that I need to keep working with this as a CGFloat after it has been formatted, I have tried taken the string back to a number by doing: `numberFromString` but the problem is that only works with a `NSNumber`.

What can I do to format my `CGFloat` and keep working with it as a `CGFloat` and not a `NSString` or `NSNumber`?

**Update** I have tried:

```
float backToFloat = [myNumber floatValue];
```

but the result is number unformatted : `0.10000` I need those extra 0s out

Comment: A float/CGFloat value does not have a "format".  It is a pure numeric value, and any "format" is imposed on it by whatever displays it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To convert `NSString` to a `CGFloat` you can use `floatValue`:

```
CGFloat *eX1rounded = [eX1F floatValue];
```

But you can round `eX1` to `eX1rounded` directly without using a number formatter,
for example:

```
CFGloat *eX1rounded = roundf(eX1F * 10.0f)/10.0f;
```

In any case, you should keep in mind that numbers like `0.1` cannot be represented
exactly as a binary floating point number.

Comment: I have tried this but ultimately I still end up with extra 0's. See updated question @MartinR

Comment: @vzm: See Hot Licks' comment: a float does not have a "format".

Answer (score 1):

Use stringWithFormat: to round and convert to a string for display purposes:

```
NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", eX1];
```

You can do the same thing in NSLog, the **%0.2f** says you want 2 decimal places.

```
NSLog(@" eX1 =%0.2f", eX1);   // this prints "0.12"
```